# RLM fit model returns "Error in `[.data.frame`(mf, xvars) : undefined columns selected"

Tags: r

I am trying to use the rlm function to create a linear model to test against my training data. Specifically, the data frame trainingData contains 100 predictors (IR Wavelengths from 852nm to 1050nm) and 1 observation (Fat). However, when I try to create a robust linear model (rlm) of the data I get the following error.

> "Error in [.data.frame(mf, xvars) : undefined columns selected"

I am trying to model all the IR wavelengths against the Fat observation, which is all contained in the data frame trainingData.

```
#Loading the "Tecator" data into R
data(tecator)

#Naming columns for easier interpretation
colnames(absorp) <- c(paste0(seq(852,1050,2),'nm'))
colnames(endpoints) <- c('Water','Fat','Protein')

#Creating training and test sets
index <- createDataPartition(endpoints[,'Fat'], p = .7, list = FALSE)
train.absorp    <- as.data.frame(absorp[index,])
test.absorp     <- as.data.frame(absorp[-index,])
train.endpoints <- as.data.frame(endpoints[index,])
test.endpoints  <- as.data.frame(endpoints[-index,])

#Creating training data frame for fat content prediction
trainingData     <- train.absorp
trainingData$Fat <- train.endpoints$Fat

rlmFitAllPredictors <- rlm(Fat ~., data = trainingData)
```

Comment: am sorry, I pulled the code out of a much larger program that I am writing and I forgot to include that I created a unified training set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue seems to be related to the column names which starts with digits.  If we change it by adding a character in front it would work

```
names(trainingData)[-ncol(trainingData)] <- paste0("X", names(trainingData)[-ncol(trainingData)])
```

-testing

```
rlmFitAllPredictors <- rlm(Fat ~., data = trainingData)
```

-output structure

```
> str(rlmFitAllPredictors)
List of 21
 $ coefficients : Named num [1:101] 4.56 13058.33 -12528.76 -13401.94 35613.86 ...
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:101] "(Intercept)" "X852nm" "X854nm" "X856nm" ...
 $ residuals    : Named num [1:152] 0.0484 0.013 -0.0547 0.0158 -0.0386 ...
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:152] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
 $ wresid       : Named num [1:152] 0.0484 0.013 -0.0547 0.0158 -0.0386 ...
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:152] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
 $ effects      : Named num [1:152] -210.4 50.5 35.7 59.2 52.3 ...
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:152] "(Intercept)" "X852nm" "X854nm" "X856nm" ...
 $ rank         : int 101
 $ fitted.values: Named num [1:152] 22.45 40.09 8.45 5.88 25.54 ...
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:152] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
...
```

---

The reason is because there is a mismatch in column names when the names starts with digits.  In the `model.matrix`, it creates the column names with backquotes.  i.e. if we add some `print` statements it would be clear

```
rlm_test <- function (formula, data, weights, ..., subset, na.action, method = c("M", 
    "MM", "model.frame"), wt.method = c("inv.var", "case"), model = TRUE, 
    x.ret = TRUE, y.ret = FALSE, contrasts = NULL) 
{
    mf <- match.call(expand.dots = FALSE)
    mf$method <- mf$wt.method <- mf$model <- mf$x.ret <- mf$y.ret <- mf$contrasts <- mf$... <- NULL
    mf[[1L]] <- quote(stats::model.frame)
    mf <- eval.parent(mf)
    method <- match.arg(method)
    wt.method <- match.arg(wt.method)
    if (method == "model.frame") 
        return(mf)
    mt <- attr(mf, "terms")
    print(mt)
    y <- model.response(mf)
    offset <- model.offset(mf)
    if (!is.null(offset)) 
        y <- y - offset
    x <- model.matrix(mt, mf, contrasts)
    print("x vars")
    print(head(x, 2))
    xvars <- as.character(attr(mt, "variables"))[-1L]
    if ((yvar <- attr(mt, "response")) > 0L) 
        xvars <- xvars[-yvar]
    xlev <- if (length(xvars) > 0L) {
        xlev <- lapply(mf[xvars], levels)
        xlev[!sapply(xlev, is.null)]
    }
    weights <- model.weights(mf)
    if (!length(weights)) 
        weights <- rep(1, nrow(x))
    fit <- rlm.default(x, y, weights, method = method, wt.method = wt.method, 
        ...)
    fit$terms <- mt
    cl <- match.call()
    cl[[1L]] <- as.name("rlm")
    fit$call <- cl
    fit$contrasts <- attr(x, "contrasts")
    fit$xlevels <- .getXlevels(mt, mf)
    fit$na.action <- attr(mf, "na.action")
    if (model) 
        fit$model <- mf
    if (!x.ret) 
        fit$x <- NULL
    if (y.ret) 
        fit$y <- y
    fit$offset <- offset
    if (!is.null(offset)) 
        fit$fitted.values <- fit$fitted.values + offset
    fit
}
```

Now test it again on the original data

```
 rlm_test(Fat ~., data = trainingData)
```

part of the output `print`ed

```
...
attr(,"predvars")
list(Fat, `852nm`, `854nm`, `856nm`, `858nm`, `860nm`, `862nm`, 
    `864nm`, `866nm`, `868nm`, `870nm`, `872nm`, `874nm`, `876nm`, 
    `878nm`, `880nm`, `882nm`, `884nm`, `886nm`, `888nm`, `890nm`, 
    `892nm`, `894nm`, `896nm`, `898nm`, `900nm`, `902nm`, `904nm`, 
    `906nm`, `908nm`, `910nm`, `912nm`, `914nm`, `916nm`, `918nm`, 
    `920nm`, `922nm`, `924nm`, `926nm`, `928nm`, `930nm`, `932nm`, 
    `934nm`, `936nm`, `938nm`, `940nm`, `942nm`, `944nm`, `946nm`, 
    `948nm`, `950nm`, `952nm`, `954nm`, `956nm`, `958nm`, `960nm`, 
    `962nm`, `964nm`, `966nm`, `968nm`, `970nm`, `972nm`, `974nm`, 
    `976nm`, `978nm`, `980nm`, `982nm`, `984nm`, `986nm`, `988nm`, 
    `990nm`, `992nm`, `994nm`, `996nm`, `998nm`, `1000nm`, `1002nm`, 
    `1004nm`, `1006nm`, `1008nm`, `1010nm`, `1012nm`, `1014nm`, 
    `1016nm`, `1018nm`, `1020nm`, `1022nm`, `1024nm`, `1026nm`, 
    `1028nm`, `1030nm`, `1032nm`, `1034nm`, `1036nm`, `1038nm`, 
    `1040nm`, `1042nm`, `1044nm`, `1046nm`, `1048nm`, `1050nm`)
```